How to set a custom package version in nix home-manager?
I'm looking for an idiomatic way of setting a custom package via home manager (I use nix package manager on MacOS)
I managed to set a custom version for pnpm package using fetchFromGitHub, but I'm not sure if it's an idiomatic way.
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

let
  pnpm94 = import (pkgs.fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "NixOS";
    repo = "nixpkgs";
    rev = "c3392ad349a5227f4a3464dce87bcc5046692fce";
    sha256 = "1klhr7mrfhrzcqfzngk268jspikbivkxg96x2wncjv1ik3zb8i75";
  }) {
    inherit (pkgs) system;
  };
in

{
 #......

  home.packages = with pkgs; [
    pnpm94.pnpm <=== our custom version of pnpm

    #... the rest of the packages
  ];
}

Is it correct approach? Or there's a more elegant alternative?

Yes, this is a correct approach. Since NixOS/nixpkgs is reproducible, the only way to use a specific version of a package is to pin the associated version/commit of nixpkgs. This method is independent of whether you're using Home Manager or not.
The simplest implementation is the one you proposed where a custom instance of pkgs is imported:
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

let
  pkgs_pnpm94 = import (pkgs.fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "NixOS";
    repo = "nixpkgs";
    rev = "c3392ad349a5227f4a3464dce87bcc5046692fce";
    sha256 = "1klhr7mrfhrzcqfzngk268jspikbivkxg96x2wncjv1ik3zb8i75";
  }) {
    inherit (pkgs) system;
  };
in

{
  home.packages = [
    # Regular packages
    pkgs.curl

    # "custom" version of `pnpm`
    pkgs_pnpm94.pnpm
  ];
}

If your configuration is organized by a flake, another way of doing it is adding this specific version of nixpkgs as an input and create an overlay. Here's an illustrative example:
{
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
    nixpkgs_pnpm94 = {
      url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/c3392ad349a5227f4a3464dce87bcc5046692fce";
    };
    home-manager = {
      url = "github:nix-community/home-manager";
      inputs.nixpkgs.follows = "nixpkgs";
    };
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, nixpkgs_pnpm94, ... }:
  let
    pkgs_pnpm94 = import nixpkgs_pnpm94 { inherit system; };
    overlay = final: prev {
      pnpm = pkgs_pnpm94.pnpm;
    };
    pkgs = import nixpkgs { inherit system; overlays = [ overlay ]; };
  in
  {
    homeConfiguration.default = home-manager.lib.homeManagerConfiguration {
      modules = [ ./home.nix ];
      inherit pkgs system;
    };
  };
}

In this example:

pkgs_pnpm94 imports the pinned version of nixpkgs for the specific commit.
An overlay is used to replace the default pnpm package with the pinned version.
home-manager then uses the modified pkgs with the overlay applied.


Thank you, Loïc, I'll mark this as an answer.
I've also realized I can use overrides e.g.
  home.packages = with pkgs; [
    (pnpm.override {
      version = "9.4.0";
      hash = "sha256-tv0L/aVV5+WErX5WswxosB1aBPnuk5ifS5PKhHPEnHQ=";
    })
    #... the rest of the packages
  ];

What do you think about overrides approach?

The override approach is also valid but may not work for more complex packages that require specific versions of their dependencies. For simpler cases like the one in this question, I would in fact recommend trying override first. If it works, great! If not, you can then switch to the methods mentioned above.
